# Uploading a resource to the FHIR server

Tags: xml, json, hl7-fhir

I am trying to upload a single resource to Grahame's server: http://hl7connect.healthintersections.com.au/open/

But I am unsure how to do so. I've been trying with something like this:

```
<Patient xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
 <identifier>400</identifier>
 <name>Adam Everyman</name>
 <telecom>555555</telecom>
 <gender>M</gender>
 <address>Address</address>
</Patient>
```

But I keep getting error messages like:

```
error - resource is nil
```

Does anyone know how this should be formatted so that Grahame's server will accept the upload?

Preferably I'd rather use JSON over XML, but if I could get either working I'd be happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, start with one of the existing examples, such as this one: http://hl7.org/implement/standards/fhir/patient-example.xml.html.

You should be able to simply post this xml to http://fhir.healthintersections.com.au/open/Patient, though you have to get the content type correct: application/xml+fhir